# IABHelper. queryInventoryAsync returns no purchases, yet launch product flow fails with "Item Already Owned"

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm experiencing an intermittent problem with In App Billing Version 3 using IABHelper as provided by Google.

Before Launching a new purchase I check for unconsumed purchases with queryInventoryAsync.  If found I consume any unconsumed purchases and begin a new transaction, if not go directly to start a new transaction. 99% of the time it works fine.

Occasionally when queryInventoryAsync returns no unconsumed purchases, the following launchPurchaseFlow fails with Response : 7: Item already owned.

```
INFO    [IABHelper] Starting async operation: refresh inventory
INFO    [IABHelper] Querying owned items, item type: inapp
INFO    [IABHelper] Package name: jp.co.mycompany.myapp
INFO    [IABHelper] Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
INFO    [IABHelper] Owned items response: 0
INFO    [IABHelper] Continuation token: null
INFO    [IABHelper] Querying SKU details.
INFO    [IABHelper] queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
INFO    [IABHelper] Querying owned items, item type: subs
INFO    [IABHelper] Package name: jp.co.mycompany.myapp
INFO    [IABHelper] Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
INFO    [IABHelper] Owned items response: 0
INFO    [IABHelper] Continuation token: null
INFO    [IABHelper] Querying SKU details.
INFO    [IABHelper] queryPrices: nothing to do because there are no SKUs.
INFO    [IABHelper] Ending async operation: refresh inventory

INFO    [IABHelper] Constructing buy intent for jp.co.mycompany.myapp.myitem, item type: inapp
INFO    [IABHelper] Launching buy intent for jp.co.mycompany.myapp.myitem Request code: 1001
INFO    [IABHelper] Ending async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
INFO    [IABHelper] Purchase canceled - Response: 7:Item Already Owned
```

queryInventoryAsync is saying the user does not own the item, but launchPurchaseFlow says the user does.

Strangely after a wait (sometimes a few minutes, sometimes more) the problem resolves itself.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

For reference I'm using the version of IABHelper last updated on March 15.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved this. It might be caused by google local caching

Comment: This also happens when you have a timeout before you can do a consume call: the item is bought but the confirmation from google never comes back to the app (timeout): the app does not know it needs to consume the purchase, unless queryInventoryAsync returns something, and it only does that a lot later because of the caching. What a joke.

Comment: And they removed unmanaged, saying that "you think about them as managed". Ok, but why stupid GooglePlay service after several hours and cleared cache still says I have no purchases??

Comment: In my case problem has nothing to do with caching - to clear cache never helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do clear cache of Google Play Service app in mobile. It may work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure such situation indicates bug in your app, but even though the Google IAP is also one of the factors which causes the problem.

Consider such situation: user purchases item, your are processing it on your server then the app crashes before the item has been consumed. The user comes back to the app, you're trying to process the item once again but IAP returns empty `Inventory` (no purchases at all). User clicks on the item to buy but receives `ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`. That's strange ?!

So there's no purchase but the item is already owned, huh? It's for sure something with local caching on the Google IAP side, but it's your app who has caused this problem (app crash). **You can wait hours but in most cases this will not solve itself**.

There are two possible solutions. The first one is good for developers, which will clear the Google IAP data.

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
```

After a few seconds you will be able to purchase the item once again.

The second solution is bad either for developer or end users. You have to restart the device. After a restart wait 20s to 5 minutes and your item will available to purchase again. If this situation occurs on your customer's device ask him/her to either clear Play Store data manually from settings or to restart the device.

Remember **the root cause is crash in your app** which mess with the IAP purchase flow before the item is consumed. Fix it and the problem will not occur any more.

Comment: No, you're wrong. Google Play IAP once again are broken. Google says in its docs that if you've purchased but not consumed product it will be returned while querying your inventory as owned. So the joke is Google again has ruined everything - I tested on several devices, it continues to say that I have no purchases while I have 2 and can't purchase them again. They killed IAP! Those bastards.

Comment: @Tertium I think there may be a bug in your app, because it works for everybody else as intended. Before you blame Google for their mistakes please check your poor code so maybe it starts working as described in the doc.

Comment: I work with android since its begining in 2009 (it was a nightmare if you want not just hacking but create a working app), with its IAPs - from v2 api. I use IAP on android, ios and windows store and I developed secure server backend not once, so I know what I'm talking about. Google almost never fix its mistakes, it just closes one service and opens another, even not trying to save an interface inheritance. I always write workarounds to get rid of  google bugs. Google with latest lib and iabhelper just doesn't f**n do what it should! What kind of error in my app can prevent getting purchases?