# Unable to buy item (response 7:item already owned) - for some users and not others

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have used the old In App billing API for over 2 years, but suddenly last week some users started complaining about not being able to restore their purchase (we only have a single non-consumable purchase). We didn't update the app in 3-4 months so it was not a code change on our part.

I rewrote everything to the v3 API and thought it would solve it, but still the same users get the error: 
"unable to buy item (response 7:item already owned)" when trying to buy it. But the product is not returned as part of the list of items the user already owns.

Seems like this is pretty much the same issue as this one: 
[IABHelper. queryInventoryAsync returns no purchases, yet launch product flow fails with "Item Already Owned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542687/iabhelper-queryinventoryasync-returns-no-purchases-yet-launch-product-flow-fai) except that in the users cases, it does not resolve itself after a few minutes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect those users have more than one account on their devices. One account is used for checking bought items, and another - for purchasing. Can you verify this? If so, a solution for them would be to install app using the same account they use for payment.

Comment: I emailed some of them, got 2 answers. Both say they have only a single account. I am considering implementing a "hack" that gives them access if the error string contains "response7" :-/

Comment: My app accepts both responses: `if (responseCode == RESPONSE_OK || responseCode == RESPONSE_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED)`. The only difference is that the product *is returned* as a part of the list of items. I would suggest to contact Google Play support.

Comment: Are you using the IabResult class? It has a "isSuccess()" method which only treats BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK as a success. I can try modifying my code to also treat BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED as success and see if I actually do get a product listing. I will update when a user has tested. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use reference implementation at all. I wrote own one based on IabHelper and IAB V3 specification. I treated both responses: OK and ALREADY_OWNED as success, because it looked logical to me.